# How to check php is loaded when using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use AJAX, and this work without problems, like this:

```
$('#main .left').load('top.php');
```

or this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/ajax_main.php',
    data: "i=ajax_call",
    success: function(msg){ 
        console.log('ok');
    }
});

// php side reprorts $_GET['i'] = "ajax_call";
```

When I set:

```
function periodicMethod(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax_main.php',
        data: "i=ajax_call",
        success: function(msg) { 
            console.log('ok');
        }
    });
}

setInterval(periodicMethod, 1000);
```

The method is called and `console.log` reports "ok" any second. This looks like 'ajax_main.php' is loaded. But in the PHP file:

**edit**

```
echo '<script>console.log("php");</script>';
```

Does not give any results. The path in URL is ok. When I change it or remove 'ajax_main.php' from server, error is reported. What may be wrong?

**edit**
another version of php:

```
<script>
function ppp()
{    console.log('sss');
}
</script>

<?
echo '<script>ppp();</script>';
?>
```

is not working to

Comment: you mean `echo "<script>console.log('php');</script>";`?

Comment: yes this my error in post

Comment: The value you return in the AJAX function is just a string, it's not actually interpreted as code, hence why you don't see `'php'` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    <script>
function periodicMethod(){
    $.ajax({type: "POST",url: 'ajax_main.php',data: "i=ajax_call",
           success: function(msg){ console.log('ok');
           jQuery("#demo_data").html(msg);
}});}

setInterval(periodicMethod, 1000);
</script>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="demo_data" id="demo_data"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just saying (useful for noobs), try adding `<script></script>` and separate the HTML code, or else they might not understand

Comment: what you mean site is inactive??

Comment: when another overlap in browser is active

Comment: function debug_to_console( $data ) {

  
        $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $data . "' );</script>";

    echo $output;
}

Comment: after use this
debug_to_console( "Test" );

Comment: Sorry for my error @Maulik, this work with empty div, youre answer is right. But question how to do it without empty div in POST way, is still unanswered

Comment: @Maulik, I use the same php file in method $('#demo_data').load('ajax_main.php'); and in $ajax POST as in my question. First work, second not.

Comment: ok use 1st and Change div to 
<input type="hidden" id="demo_data" name="demo_data"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108627/discussion-between-maulik-and-skippy).